# Rails - how to update existing Facebook status with Koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Is there any way to modify current content (status update) on my Facebook wall (or on the wall of my Facebook page) with using (in the best way) the **Koala** gem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit any fields in the status message object. 
[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/).